How to get the right timezone in Java with ZonedDateTime?
My front-end send me a datetime string with an offset in a Post Mapping, such as : 2024-04-12T10:39:23+02:00
My goal is to map this datetime in my backend (java spring boot) and I want to keep the offset information, so I thinked about using a ZoneDateTime object.
But this is not working, my ZonedDateTime is 2024-04-12T08:39:23[UTC], offset is set to Z which is wrong, it's +2.
Why does it not handle the offset? Is there any other solution?
Thank you.
EDIT:
Here is my post mapping:
@PostMapping(value = "/test",
        produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public String test(
        @Valid
        @RequestBody
        TestObject test) {
    return "OK";
}

And my TestObject
package blabla;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.time.OffsetDateTime;

@Getter
@Setter
public class TestObject {
    private OffsetDateTime date;
}


There is no time zone information in that. There is an offset though, so consider using an OffsetDateTime. Please show a [mcve] of the code that is not working.

I take it that when you say time zone, you mean UTC offset (neither something like Europe/Rome nor Central European Summer Time).

In fact, afaik the current JDBC standard only supports OffsetDateTime (which you have there as far as data are concerned). Best and most precise practice would probably be to store an instant and zone separately. No zone in your data, as has been said

Yes, sorry about it i meant offset, not a timezone. I edited my original post.
I also tried with OffsetDateTime, but I get Z as offset in my object, I really don't get it, offset in my string seems to be bypassed

String o = "2024-04-12T10:39:23+02:00";System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse(o).toInstant()); Now store the tz too.

The problem is that I want it to be mapped when the post request is made, I don't want to use parsing, I added a code example. Thank you for your help!!

I don't know that API but Id guess parsing would happen automatically

As an aside, does your database field support other offsets than zero? Many don't.
